# Can I mount a rack on eyelets that aren't horizontal?

Tags: frames, rack, panniers

The eyelets at the lower end of my frame's seatstays are not aligned with the dropouts (to allow attachment of a vertical rack strut). The misalignment is around 13°.

Two questions:

1. What options do I have for mounting a rack on them?
2. Is this in any way "normal" for rack eyelets?

I believe the outside eyelets, shown below, are for the rack and the inside ones are for a mudguard/fender stay.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't need to use both of these eyelets to mount a rack. Probably just the outside one. So the fact they are not "parallel" (you meant "aligned" I think) is not an issue.

Comment: @dvmac What I meant by parallel was that the *corresponding* eyelets on each side of the bike are not parallel. I'll make the wording in the question clearer.

Comment: @WillVousden only one side of the bike is visible in the photo...

Comment: @davmac You may assume that the seatstays are symmetric :-)

Comment: @WillVousden except for the eyelets, you mean? Sorry for being pedantic but I really almost can't believe it until I can see it!

Comment: @davmac I added a photo of the other side of the bike – hopefully that clears it up!

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood. You are saying that the eyelet holes are not horizontal, not that the eyelets on either side of the bike are at a different height, right? That does indeed seem like it could be a problem for some racks (although not as much as what I first thought you were saying!). That said, you might find the rack attachment points have some tolerance and don't need to screw in perfectly horizontally.

Comment: @davmac Right, what I really should've said is that they're not aligned with the dropouts. I have one steel rack (a Tubus) that definitely requires properly aligned eyelets. Another aluminium one that I have is a bit more flexible (fits on another bike with slightly misaligned eyelets), but not enough to accommodate the ~10° angle that these are at.

Answer (score 10):

Just an idea: V-brakes shoes typically come with "cups and cones" (the aluminium parts between the shoe itself and the nut in the picture below), to allow a correction of the alignment. Not sure that it would be OK in terms of diameter though (V-brake shoes usually use larger bolts, but it can be too large).

You can just repurpose such parts to correct the misalignment between the rack mount and the bolt axle.

[image]

EDIT: Answer the second subquestion. This layout seems very unusual for me. The most common way is to have the eyelets close to the dropout (see other image below). But that being said, I noticed a trend to have fenders/racks sold for specific bike models, that then have custom attachment points — for example the Canyon Grizl has eyelets in the middle of the seat stay, inside. Another trend is to consider the fenders and rack as an integrated part, and then only requiring one pair of eyelets (example Cube Nuroad FE).

[image]

Comment: V brakes use M6, racks are almost always M5.  so they should work, but you might want to add an M5 washer under the bolt head

Comment: The presence of the inner (mudguard) eyelets suggests they want to sell you their accessories too.

Answer (score 3):

With my Tortec Velocity Hybrid and Topeak Super Tourist racks, I'd probably pre-bend the rack for this much of an angle.  For that I'd use an adjustable spanner, being sure to insert the end of the rack stay by the same amount on each side.  The pre-bend doesn't have to be perfect, just a step in the right direction.

For a smaller angle I didn't even do that, just put both screws in finger tight, then tightened them in turns progressively.

Those racks both have a fairly light plate at the end of the stay assembly.

A rack with a sturdier plate will be harder to pre-bend.  The stays themselves will bend in preference to the plate, which would be OK if done in a controlled way - and that's not easy.